# Shutdown infinite async generator

Tags: python, python-asyncio

#### Reproducible error

I tried to reproduce the error in an online REPL [here](https://repl.it/repls/SphericalMobilePyramid). However, it is not exactly the same implementation (and hence behavior) as my real code (where I do `async for response in position_stream()`, instead of `for position in count()` in the REPL).

#### More details on my actual implementation

I define somewhere a coroutine like so:

```
async def position(self):
    request = telemetry_pb2.SubscribePositionRequest()
    position_stream = self._stub.SubscribePosition(request)

    try:
        async for response in position_stream:
            yield Position.translate_from_rpc(response)
    finally:
        position_stream.cancel()
```

where position_stream is infinite (or possibly very long lasting). I use it from an example code like this:

```
async def print_altitude():
    async for position in drone.telemetry.position():
        print(f"Altitude: {position.relative_altitude_m}")
```

and `print_altitude()` is run on the loop with:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(print_altitude())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

That works well. Now, at some point, I'd like to close the stream from the caller. I thought that I could just run  `asyncio.ensure_future(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())` and wait for my `finally` close above to get called, but it doesn't happen.

Instead, I receive a warning on an unretrieved exception:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<print_altitude() done, defined at [...]
```

Why is that, and how can I make it such that all my async generators actually get closed (and run their `finally` clause)?

Comment: Including a minimal _runnable_ [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question might help with getting an answer.

Comment: I tried to make a minimal one [here](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/e3x6b4FQB98jHiPqzH6y/), but it's not exactly the same as my streams are not `async for` but just normal `for`s (see lines 6 and 14).

Comment: I edited my question accordingly, and I found a nice online REPL: [here](EDIT: I tried to reproduce in an online REPL to reproduce ([here](https://repl.it/repls/SphericalMobilePyramid))

Comment: But the finally clauses are getting called in your example, because I am getting "position stream cancelled" and "altitude stream cancelled" in stdout. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well in the example that's right, but I still get this `Task exception was never retrieved` Runtime error. It is not the real code as I actually use an `async for` in my real code, but I did not find a way to write a small example perfectly reproducing the error. I was hoping that my toy example would show what I am doing wrong (i.e. that fixing this RuntimeError would fix my real issue).

Comment: `RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop`. You are trying to close an event loop that is currently executing a coroutine. Removing `loop.close()` gets rid of that error.

Comment: But removing `loop.close()` also means that I will not close the event loop, which I am trying to do. Right?

Comment: Well, as you see in the error message, you can't close the event loop from the inside of it. To close a loop (why though?), you really need to stop it first.

Comment: I edited my example to add a `cleanup_task()`. This task waits for a few seconds, and then tries to close all the tasks. The idea is that this task detects that the code should end. I could probably `exit(0)` there, but that's probably not considered elegant. And because those streams are infinite, I cannot just wait for them to finish, can I?

Comment: When I saw the sleep lines, my heart was stuck. You cannot use a  "non-synchronous " Loop If a result comes from different data sources. The delay option is left on the hardware. The cycle cannot be infinite, it needs a trigger to be stable. Infinite loops cannot be terminated, only triggers are not sent to the loops. Mathematical mean or derivatives are used for applications with a fuzzy loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. The sleep lines are here to simulate a real-life stream, because it's not convenient for me to plug a real sensor into repl.it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you `stop` a loop, none of your coroutines will have a chance to shut down properly. Calling `close` basically means irreversibly destroying the loop.

If you do not care what happens to those running tasks, you can simply `cancel` them all, this will stop asynchronous generators as well:

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import suppress


async def position_stream():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        yield 0

async def print_position():
    async for position in position_stream():
        print(f'position: {position}')

async def cleanup_awaiter():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('cleanup!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        asyncio.ensure_future(print_position())
        asyncio.ensure_future(print_position())
        loop.run_until_complete(cleanup_awaiter())
        # get all running tasks:
        tasks = asyncio.gather(*asyncio.Task.all_tasks())
        # schedule throwing CancelledError into the them:
        tasks.cancel()
        # allow them to process the exception and be cancelled:
        with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
            loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
    finally:
        print('closing loop')
        loop.close()
```

Comment: `task.cancel()` is interesting! I'll check that tomorrow!